# Was Antigonus of Socho a student of Shimon HaTzadik?

Tags: commentaries, mishna, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Have any commentaries on Pirkei Avot 1:2-3 questioned whether Antigonus of Socho was a student of Shimon HaTzadik or cast doubt on whether the two were contemporaries?

Premise of the question: In *The Jewish Spiritual Heroes* it states: "There is even some doubt as to whether Antigonos was the direct successor of Simon the Just or whether he lived some generations later."

Comment: Can you explain the premise of your question? The Mishnah explicitly says he received his tradition from Shimon HaTzadik. Why do you ask if there are those that question that?

Comment: @robev In "The Jewish Spiritual Heroes" it states: "There is even some doubt as to whether Antigonos was the direct successor of Simon the Just or whether he lived some generations later." So I'm wondering if any commentaries make the same observation?

Comment: @GGG you should add your motivation into the question Itself, so people reading it can understand the question. Also, it has to do with the “missing years” in the Jewish calendar.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_years_(Jewish_calendar)

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40640/was-shimon-hatzaddik-the-first-tanna

Answer (score 2):

R Avigdor Miller in his history books maintained there was only one Shimon Hatzaddik, i dont recall the exact arguments. Anyway, I would expect this to be dealt with more by religious historians than commentators. Doros Harishonim probably talks about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a question about the identity of "Shimon haTzadik". Josephus identified Shimon haTzadik as Shimon I, but most scholars now say he is Shimon II. Antigonus of Sokho probably lived in the time of Shimon II, given his Greek name and his successors. So if Shimon haTzadik is Shimon I, Antigonus probably lived a century later.

Comment: So, have any commentaries pointed out that there were two Shimons and that Antigonus was an associate of the latter rather than the former?

Comment: See מורה נבוכי הזמן pg. 103, דברי הימים לבני ישראל pg. 89,  ספר דור דור ודורשיו pg. 95.

Comment: In ספר דור דור ודורשיו, is it showing dates of birth or death next to the names?

Comment: I don't see any dates next to the names? https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dor_dor_%E1%B9%BFe_dorsha%E1%B9%BF/SV8pAAAAYAAJ?gbpv=1&pg=PA94

Comment: Seems I'm looking at the wrong book, my bad. Could you clarify the names of the authors of the other books too, please?

Comment: No problem, https://books.google.co.il/books?id=GtUFcSlkpKUC&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q&f=false and https://www.google.com/books/edition/Divre_ha_yamim_li_vene_Yi%C5%9Bra%CA%BEel/9QE_AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA39&printsec=frontcover